# How to make Windows execute my Python script files when I click them

Tags: python, windows-10

I have made a Python program that uses `output.to_csv('results.csv')`. When I run it in `Spyder` it creates that CSV file. But when I double click on it nothing happens. Cmd appears and closes but nothing on the folder, no `results.csv`.

What am I missing? What more do I have to do?

Comment: Try right clicking on the file and open with notepad or excel?

Comment: This question is not really Python-related, it should be posed as "How to make Windows execute my script files when I click them".

Comment: Try running the program in a command window or powershell, to see if it is throwing an error

Answer (score 1):

Run the program from the command line itself instead of double-clicking the `.py` file.

I assume you are on Windows since you mention CMD. First, `cd` into the directory containing your program. Then, run `python <program>.py` or `python3 <program>.py` depending on your installation.

This time, you will see any output or error messages that appear in CMD without it immediately closing.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bernie\Desktop\tasos\akopatsa.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas`......This is what i get when i try to run it with IDLE

Comment: You are missing a dependency. Try `python -m pip install pandas` to install it.

Answer (score 0):

If the `.csv` file really exists, you should be able to go to your File Explorer and find the file at the top of the "Quick Access" section. Right-click the file and hover over "Open With >". Then select Notepad and a notepad will open up showing your results.

If you do not see the file, then try running your program on the command prompt (for Windows):

- Press the windows key and type "cmd" in the search bar.
- Choose "Command Prompt"
- Go to the dir of your program using the `cd` command
- Type `python <program name>.py`
- If there are no errors, follow the steps in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i guess windows is not recommended at all for this type of tasks. I mean running something simple as create such file is like trying to kill the Lernaean Hydra. 
What i did is i just runned it with anaconda prompt and it worked sweet! Thanks for help. Thanks to all!

PS: I'm seriously considering changing to Linux after this

For anyone having the same problem, but have anaconda installed. 1) Open Anaconda Prompt, 2) use cd (1 space) then adress of the folder which contains your py program (eg. `cd C:\Users\Bernie\Desktop\tasos`) and hit enter, 3) on the next line that appears type: `python program_name.py`, 4)Hit enter, 5)success!